# How to prevent XElement value from using locale formatting?

Tags: .net, linq, excel

I am in the US, and my colleague is in Russia.  We are each using the following blurb:

```
        Dim num As Single = 0.123
        Dim myData As XElement
        myData = New XElement(myPrefix + "Data", New XAttribute(myPrefix + "Type", "Number"), New XAttribute("foo", "bar"))
        myData.Value = num
```

However when we examine myData in Quickwatch or save the content to XML, he sees **0,123** and I see **0.123**, which is obviously based upon our locale.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?  Our code is exporting this value to an XML file and we are opening it in Excel, and the values are incorrect because of this locale issue.  We each created a simple Excel file in XML format and the underlying data is alawys in US (dot versus comma) format.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
newData.Value = num
```

The type of `XElement.Value` is `String`, so you're using the "standard" conversion from `Single` to `String` - I suspect if you had `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit` turned on, this would cause a compile-time failure.

In order to set the value according to normal LINQ to XML rules, you need:

```
newData.ReplaceAll(num)
```

Or to just add a text value but preserve child elements:

```
newData.Add(num)
```

(It's not clear where `newData` has come from to be honest - you've shown `myData` but not `newData`.)

Comment: ooops... I failed to rename one of my variables for this post.  I fixed it above